# How can I map a relative path outside of the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, path, relative-path

I have some service which does some file processing. It may need to map to arbitrary paths, and I'm tried to keep it as decoupled from a controller as possible. Normally, I could just do something like:

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/");
var imageFile = Path.Combine(path, filename);
```

But if I'm trying to do this outside of a controller, I don't have access to `Server`. Is there any simple and clean way I could map to paths without relying on `Server`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DynamicDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.dynamicdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) can give you the directory the application domain is executed from, which is independent of any controllers and can be used through your whole application.